# Selenoid Docker ssl certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, selenoid

I am trying to add ssl certificates to my container. Is there any specific location to add these certificates for example /etc/selenoid?

Because the certificates are not being recognized.

Tried using the --volume command

docker run --volume /etc/folder_location:/etc/selenoid

When I do a docker inspect the volumes parameter is "null" and the mounts parameter does not have the location of the certificates.

Using CentOS. Please Advise.

UPDATE: By referring to the link provided in the comments section by Vania, I am trying to add the .pem.cer files while starting the docker

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ${HOME}:/root -e OVERRIDE_HOME=${HOME} -e ROOT_CA_SELENOID_CA_CERTS aerokube/cm:latest selenoid start --port 4444
```

Is there any way to verify that the security certificates are properly added to the selenoid container?

Still getting connection refused error while trying to access this container

Comment: See https://aerokube.com/images/latest/#_adding_custom_root_certification_authority

Comment: @vania-pooh I have updated my question. Still getting connection refused error. Is there anything else that I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following this link provided by vania. I was able to add certificates

https://aerokube.com/images/latest/#_adding_custom_root_certification_authority

docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ${HOME}:/root -e OVERRIDE_HOME=${HOME} -e ROOT_CA_SELENOID_CA_CERTS aerokube/cm:latest selenoid start --port 4444

Answer (score 1):

After starting docker you should be able to see the contents of the volume using this command:

```
docker exec -it <container> ls <location of volume>
```

For your case:

```
docker exec -it <container> ls /etc/selenoid
```

You could also run the "sh" or "bash" command to gain access to the containers bash shell.